# Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember returns "does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present" despite the ID existing

Tags: powershell, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to return a list of users within a certain Azure AD Role, say Application Administrators, for example.

I'm running the cmdlet Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember from the Microsoft.Graph SDK module (the SDK being new to me), but running into an error for every role I try to query.

```
Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3"
```

But it returns (for any role ID):

```
Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember : Resource '9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a ...
```

The Role ID of "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3" is universal for the Application Administrator, as is shown in the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) for App Admin Template ID. So I know that it's a correct ID for that role template.

My only other thought is permission based, checking the required roles for this command by using `Find-MgGraphCommand -command Get-MGDirectoryRoleMember | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Permissions`

I find that **RoleManagement.Read.Directory** should be all that is required according to this corresponding description it returns:

```
Allows the app to read the role-based access control (RBAC) settings for your company's directory, on your behalf.  This includes reading directory role templates, directory roles and memberships.
```

Any direction would be much appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: This really turned into a question on the difference between Get-MGDirectoryRole and Get-MGDirectoryRoleTemplate. My last comment on scottwtang's answer clarifies the difference with a link to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked contains the **role template ID**, the cmdlet `Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember` requires the **role ID**.

You can get the role ID using `Get-MgDirectoryRole`. See the object output below with the 2 different Ids.

```
DeletedDateTime      : 
Description          : Can create and manage all aspects of app registrations and enterprise apps.
DisplayName          : Application Administrator
Id                   : b68e3c0d-282b-4914-bd21-f1e11f4562a0
Members              : 
RoleTemplateId       : 9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3
ScopedMembers        : 
AdditionalProperties : {}
```

**Example**

You can first use `Get-MgDirectoryRole` to get the role ID, and then feed it into `Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember`

```
$roleName = "Application Administrator"

# Get the directory role
$adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$RoleName'"

# Get all role assignments
Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $adminRole.Id
```

Note, if the admin role hasn't been activated (the role has not ever been assigned), `Get-MgDirectoryRole` will fail, so you need to activate the role first.

```
$roleName = "Application Administrator"

# Get the directory role
$adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$RoleName'"

# If the role hasn't been activated, we need to get the role template ID to first activate the role
if ($adminRole -eq $null)
{
    $adminRoleTemplate = Get-MgDirectoryRoleTemplate | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $RoleName}
    $adminRole = New-MgDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $adminRoleTemplate.Id
}

# Get all role assignments
Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $adminRole.Id
```

Comment: I wasn't aware there was an Id AND a RoleTemplateId, thank you for pointing this out. It was especially problematic because I was using the command "Get-MGDirectoryRoleTemplate" only to avoid, as you put it, situations where the role was not activated. That command apparently does NOT return the actual ID , but rather only the templateID which is why I never found that other ID.

Comment: As a clarification, are you aware of the differences between Get-MgDirectoryRole and Get-MgDirectoryRoleTemplate? I thought that it was related to PIM (Privileged IDentity Management) partially. As in, if a user is assigned App Administrator but is eligible only, they won't show up in Get-MGDirectoryRole? But I see you mentioned it is if the role has never been assigned generally, is that regardless of a PIM status?

Comment: Found docs relating to your point above about activation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

"This operation only returns roles that have been activated. A role becomes activated when an admin activates the role using the Activate directoryRole API. Not all built-in roles are initially activated.

When assigning a role using the Azure portal, the role activation step is implicitly done on the admin's behalf. To get the full list of roles that are available in Azure AD, use List directoryRoleTemplates."

Thanks for the help!